# Extract json subset with few attributes from the main json

Tags: java, json

Is there an API/tool available for extracting specific attributes(json subset) of a json in java, similar to apache-commons beanutils copy?

For example I have the following JSON

```
{
    "fixed":[
        {
        "b":"some value",
        "c":"some value",
        "d":"some value",
        "e":"some value",
        "f":"some value"
        },
        {
        "b":"value",
        "c":"value",
        "d":"value",
        "e":"value",
        "f":"value"
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to have the following json

```
{
    "fixed":[
        {
        "b":"some value",
        "e":"some value",
        "f":"some value"
        },
        {
        "b":"value",
        "e":"value",
        "f":"value"
        }
    ]
}
```

I came up the following method, but not sure if its the right approach

```
public JSONObject parseJSON(JSONObject data,List<String> subset){
        JSONArray fixedArray = (JSONArray) data.get("fixed");
        JSONObject resObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray resArray = new JSONArray();
        for(int i=0;i<fixedArray.size();i++){
            JSONObject element = (JSONObject) fixedArray.get(i);
            JSONObject resElement = new JSONObject();
            for(String s:subset){
                resElement.put(s, element.get(s));
            }
            resArray.add(resElement);
        }
        return resObj.put("fixed", resArray);
}
```

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33473571/how-to-extract-a-json-subset-from-main-json) SO question, but wasn't helpful for this topic.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/arch.html you can also create you own pojo class from JAXB ,if you want.